# Python: Add 1 every month in dataframe for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe:

```
            A    B   C
date
2021-01-01  1    nan 1
2021-01-23  nan  1   1
2021-02-03  1    nan 1
```

How can I add "1" to all columns at the beginning of each month? (Note I also want to do this quarterly as well) The dataframe should end up looking like this:

```
            A   B   C
date
2021-01-01  2   nan 2
2021-01-23  nan 1   1
2021-02-01  nan 1   1
2021-02-03  1   nan 1
```

The beginning of the month should have "nan" in the same place as the last instance of the previous month.

Comment: Why `A` column is `NaN` for `2021-02-01`?

Comment: It's just how the data is. Check the edited question please. Thank you

Comment: Note that it's easier to work with example data if you include something that can be easily copied-and-pasted, like CSV.

Comment: Why do you expect `2021-02-01  nan 1   1` and not `2021-02-01  nan 2   2`? as it is the beginning of a month. Or did you add the row as it is missing from the input data?

Comment: The beginning of each month follows the last input of the previous month.

Comment: Check my solution below. Thanks all for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC the logic, you could do:

```
# ensure datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# fill missing starts of month
idx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='MS')
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(idx))

# update starts of month
prev = df.shift(1).loc[idx] # get last data of previous month
df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx].add(1).combine_first(prev) # increment/fill
```

output:

```
              A    B    C
2021-01-01  2.0  NaN  2.0
2021-01-23  NaN  1.0  1.0
2021-02-01  NaN  1.0  1.0
2021-02-03  1.0  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: What freq would I use for quarterly?

Comment: You mean in place of month? From the top of my head i'd say 'QS' but better check the doc.

Comment: [list of frequency aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df.index.is_month_end) & (df.index >= df.first_valid_index())]+=1
```

Figured it out. And, for quarterly, it would be `.is_quarter_end`

Comment: This might work for your use case, but it doesn't seem to answer the question you asked.